# File manager doesn't remember list preference

Tags: vmware, filemanager, vmware-player

On my Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine (on VMWare Player), I have set my preference in the file manager to "View items as a list" (click image to enlarge):

[image: View items as a list]

But every time if I start up my virtual machine and open my file manager, I get the grid and not the list.

How can I make sure that Ubuntu remembers my preference and always shows the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file manager go to preferences and set `View new folders using` to `List View`.
This will change the default view, which should stick after a reboot.